# Problem with displaying information from DB

Tags: php

```
//conn to DB     
echo $_POST['text'];
$filter = $_POST['text'];
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM contents
WHERE
MATCH(content,title) AGAINST ('$filter')
";
$mksql=mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($mksql)) {
echo $row['title']."<br />";
}
```

I send POST request to another page with the above code.
It echoes me what I wrote in the input field but it doesn't output any result.
When I run the query in phpmyadmin in works and outputs me 1 result.
Where's the problem?

Comment: note : easy to hack without a proper filter.

Comment: also, what's the string you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks I will add htmlspecialchars!

Comment: @yoda the string is "dinosaur"

Comment: htmlspecialchars has nothing to do with SQL

Comment: and you say the exact same string and query turn out different results on phpmyadmin?

Comment: @yoda yes ,that's the strange thing!

Comment: first of all print your query out and compare with one from phpmyadmin

Comment: I did that ,I echo $sql and copy and paste it to phpmyadmin.Again different results!

Comment: well, either there are some errors, but you don't see it or you're querying different databases

Comment: The problem was in the encoding

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM contents 
WHERE MATCH(content,title) AGAINST ('$filter' IN BOOLEAN MODE ) ";
```

Before query any fulltext search you must create mysql fulltext indexing.

Execute this query in phpmyadmin.

```
ALTER TABLE contents ADD FULLTEXT(content, title);
```

Answer (score 0):

may be there is problem in the post data which is not matching with full text search. you can use **mysql_escape_string()**, **htmlspecialchars()** functions for the post data you are using for query. These functions will help avoiding html tags,quotes,etc. you can print the generated sql and run that query in phpmyadmin. and of course create mysql fulltext indexing for the field you are searching.